# Deny Delete to An Active Directory Account in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, security

I want to deny an AD account to delete any record in sql server. How can i do that? 
DENY DELETE TO [usergorup\username] did not work. Is there another way?

Comment: What permissions are currently granted? Accounts can't delete data without having permission to do so.

Comment: There is a SQLDML permission on the User Mapping -> Database role membership for. How can i find that SQLDML permission? Where does it take place? Thank you.

Comment: When you say it "didn't work", what exactly have you tried and what happened?

Comment: Yes. I executed this query DENY DELETE TO [usergorup\username] . And command completed succesfully but the users still could be able to delete any record on the database

Comment: Could you produce a [repro] please?

Comment: Sorry. could not understand clearly. Do you want me to write the query?

Comment: `DENY DELETE TO`only denies the user in the current database where you execute the statement. Not the entire server/login.

Comment: @RandiVertongen I have solved my issue with your information. I applied the command to the all databases in the server. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Omer Great, most of it was you, no need to thank me :). Good luck!

Comment: @JohnEisbrener I answered my question. Thank you very much for reminding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by executing "DENY DELETE TO [UserGroup\UserName]" statement one by one in every databases on the server. It will solve your issue if you have same situation like this.